Cloud Formation: api-key invalid altough it is valid - regional Api Gateway
I have an API with Api Key enabled.
I've:

created an Usage plan
attached the Api key
added the Api stage
then Deployed it.

I still get Forbidden message. (Yes, I've added the Api Key in header)
The API is created with Cloud Formation, but theUsage plan and Api are created in AWS console.
I've tried to create the API in the console too, still the same error.
